# Compass heading - multiple rotations

Tags: javascript, math, compass

I am currently prototyping a web app which is using the compass heading in a browser. This is a value ranging from 0 ~ 360.

Whenever i do a full rotation the value jumps from 360 back to 0.
I cannot figure out how i can get it to increase from 360 to for example 720 on the second rotation.

What piece of math magic am i missing?

Thanks!

This is my code

```
        if ('ondeviceorientationabsolute' in window) {
            window.addEventListener('deviceorientationabsolute', handleOrientationAbsolute);
        } else if ('ondeviceorientation' in window) {
            window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', handleOrientation);
        }

        function handleOrientationAbsolute(e) {
            alpha = Math.round(360 - e.alpha);
            update();
        }

        function handleOrientation(e) {
            alpha = Math.round(e.webkitCompassHeading);
            update();
        }


        function update() {
            headingEl.innerHTML =  alpha; //This value should be able to return higher than 360
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll steal a technique from Mario Kart.

Have, around your circle, certain thresholds. You need to divide the circle into at least 3 groups. (Let's say you're using the `120°` points.) Store which group you're in (e.g. `0`, `1` or `2`), and every so often check which group you are in. If you change between `0` and `1`, or `1` and `2`, just store that. But if you change between `2` and `0`, increment or decrement a counter.

This will allow you to return values greater than 360°.

Comment: Oh that actually makes sense. I will give this a try when i get to the office. May i ask where i can find this mario kart stuff? Im highly interested!

Comment: @MichaelKoelewijn On Nintendo games consoles. If you clip through walls it's quite obvious what's going on.